# Disabling FocusVisualStyle per application

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I have problem with `FocusVisualStyle` in my application.

I would like to disable it globally, but I cannot get it done. I have created 2 styles:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Setter
        Property="FocusVisualStyle"
        Value="{x:Null}" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
    <Setter
        Property="FocusVisualStyle"
        Value="{x:Null}" />
</Style>
```

And placed it at the beginning of `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries` of my App.

Unfortunately, this is not working.

I am using MahApp.Metro and DevExpress and this might be a problem here.

Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: "This is not working" as in how?

Comment: I mean, most controls still have FocusVisualStyle in my application.

Comment: Maybe because you are overriding the implicit style and setting one yourself. Or maybe there is a style somewhere near the element which overrides the application-wide style?